# Finding image to display in github issue

Tags: image, rest, github

I'm trying to display an image in an issue that I've sent to a github repo. I've set up a feedback widget that allows a user to send a screenshot along with a description of their issue. For this I'm using both the [put document](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents) and the [post issue](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-an-issue) api. To separate the documents in the repo from my feedback items I have used the path /feedback. The URI looks something like this:

https://{host}/{owner}/{reponame}/contents/feedback/{filename}

NOTE: I'm sending images via base64 after parsing with html2canvas. The format I've set as default is .png so the filename is typically _user_filename.png.

Via the [repo contents api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content) I can see that the image was successfully sent. From the response I can use any number of URIs to get a hold of this document again but what I'd ultimately like to do is reference it in an issue. In my subsequent post to the issue api I'm sending then the following:

URI: https://{host}/{owner}/{reponame}/issues
Body Content:

```
{
  "title": "user defined",
  "body": "
     Browser Info: some browser data
     Description : some further description
     Screenshot: ![/feedback/filename](https://git.i.{domain}/{owner}/{reponame}/git/blobs/{blobId})
"
}
```

The issue is successfully created but the screenshot isn't being displayed. I've tried all other links I've received that I can view via the repo contents api but none seem to work (e.g. url, html_url, git_url, download_url, self, git etc..).

I'm not sure if it is relevant but I'll mention it anyway: I'm using Git Enterprise v3.5.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? The documentation seems to be fairly scattered when trying to achieve what I'm attempting to do so any help would be much appreciated! And let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks!